# Strange results with pthread execution

Tags: macos, pthreads

I have this code to test the pthread in Mac OS X.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//    A thread that just exits
void*  mythread(void *arg) { 
    int tArg;

    tArg = *(int*)arg;
    printf("Received %d\n", tArg);
    return 0; 
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int err, count = 0;

    pthread_t thread;

    while (1) {
        err = pthread_create(&thread, 0, mythread, &count);
        if (err != 0) {
            printf("Count: %d Error: %d '%s'\n", count, err, strerror(err));
        }
        count += 500;
        if (count == 5000) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is one of the results:

```
Received 3000
Received 3500
Received 3000
Received 3500
Received 3000
Received 3000
Received 3500
Received 4500
Received 4500
Received -2009390077
```

The results seem to strange to me as it doesn't start with 0, and multiple duplicates and weird last value. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the `thread` on every iteration, this is going to have unexpected consequences.

You are passing the address of `count` to the thread (int*), that it starts at `3000` is no surprise; By the time the first thread is actually executing the `int` at `*count` must already be incremented to that value.

Other threads concurrently read the same value from the stack of the main process, so you get repetition.

The last result can be explained because the threads are not joined appropriately. By the time the last thread reads `count` the variable is no longer on the stack because the main function returned, or is returning.

The correct code should look more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//    A thread that just exits
void*  mythread(void *arg) { 
    int tArg;

    tArg = *(int*)arg;
    printf("Received %d\n", tArg);
    return 0; 
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int err, num = 0, count[10];
    pthread_t thread[10];

    for (num = 0; num < 10; num++) {
        /* this is horrible, these could be statically initialized */
        if (!num) 
            count[num] = 500;
        else count[num] = count[num-1] + 500;

        /* each thread should have it's own pthread_t and int* */
        /* do not change the count[num] of another thread */
        err = pthread_create(&thread[num], 0, mythread, &count[num]);
        if (err != 0) {
            printf("Count: %d Error: %d '%s'\n", count[num], err, strerror(err));
        }
    }

    for (num = 0; num < 10; num++) {
        pthread_join(thread[num], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that still there are no guarantees for order of execution, and you might get output like:

```
Received 1000
Received 2000
Received 2500
Received 1500
Received 500
Received 3000
Received 3500
Received 4000
Received 4500
Received 5000
```

This is normal.